# DOS codepage in SciTE under Linux

Tags: linux, linux-mint, character-encoding, scite

I want to edit text files in old [DOS code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:DOS_code_pages) (CP866 in my case) using SciTE.
But I cannot configure SciTE.

These parameters work excellently with Windows:

```
code.page=866
output.code.page=866
character.set=255
```

but do not work with Linux (I'm using Linux Mint).
SciTE for Linux shows symbols from another codepage, not 866.

What values should I assign to parameters `code.page` and `character.set`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some patch for linux version of scite https://sourceforge.net/p/scintilla/feature-requests/1019/ and then character.set will be 866 while code.page=0 (for single byte encodings)